# Excel MATCH() function - Zero matches blank

Tags: excel, excel-match

Im using the `MATCH()` function to decice the row number for the `INDEX()` function. I am using exact match (0) as parameter. This works fine for the majority of the time, however:

*Why does it create a match when one cell is blank/empty and the other contains zero?*

I could probably make some IF-statement, ignoring zero values, to counter this effect. But it seems silly and I would also like to understand the underlying logic behind this mechanic, for future usage.

Edit:
As requested, here is the function of which I speak...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('RMED Visual Inspection'!$A:$B; MATCH(A2; 'RMED Visual Inspection'!$A:$A; 0); 2); 0)
```

The `lookup_value` is blank. The `lookup_array` consist of numbers from 0 and up. `MATCH()` will return the number of the first row in the `lookup_array` that is 0.

Comment: What are you passing as `lookup_value`?

Comment: The `lookup_value` is a blank/empty field (nothing entered in it, not even ""). And that `lookup_value` creates a match with the first zero in the `lookup_array`

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: Added it to the original post...

Comment: Indeed Microsoft would be the best to answer this. However the response time is usually a lot quicker in here, and what people know continues to surpise me, so I decided to give it a shot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Microsoft Excel, when you use a formula that tests for a **zero**
>   value, you may see unexpected results if the cell is blank.
>   **Microsoft Excel interprets a blank cell as zero, and not as empty or blank.** Therefore, any cells that are blank are evaluated as zero in
>   the function.

And this is the reason you are getting the number of the first row that is 0.

Check **[this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214244)** link for more information.

Another thing which I've noticed is that you are trying to find a row number which you already know using `A2` in your **`Match`** function.

My suggestion would be to change all the blank cells with 0 or some value if you really want to use your formula. You can do in many different ways.

One way is using Go To Special function to fill blank cells with 0 or other specific value and another option is to use small macro to do so.

You can get more info on **[this](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/772-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-0-or-specific-value.html)** page.

Comment: Thanks. I ended uo with a work around using `IF()` to ignore blank cells. But its nice to know that it is just the way the mechanics works, and not something I did wrong :-)